# How can I cancel the identityy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, crud

0

I work in asp.NetCore mvc technology. I was able to connect 2 tables according to FK and PK, When I perform an insert operation to db. The identity of my table is advanced and what happens is that there is no data at all on the table so it gives me blank data. Image: enter image description here When I add data then I do not update the table name I selected and I added another category with a blank name and advanced identity I defined in OnModelCreating 5 types of names and the identity progresses to 6 as seen in the image

My Models:

```
public Animal()
    {
        Category = new Category();
    }
    [Key]
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Portrait")]
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [InverseProperty("Animals")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
    //[InverseProperty("Animal")]
    //public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Animals = new HashSet<Animal>();
    }

    [Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Category")]
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public partial class PetDb : DbContext
{
    public PetDb()
    {

    }
    public PetDb(DbContextOptions<PetDb> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasData(
            new { AnimalId = 1, Name = "Shoko", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-12), Description = "Friendly and loyal", CategoryId = 1, PhotoUrl = "ShokoDog.jpg" });
        });

        _ = modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
          entity.HasData(
           new { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Dogs" },
           new { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Cats" },
           new { CategoryId = 3, Name = "Birds" },
           new { CategoryId = 4, Name = "Rabbits" },
           new { CategoryId = 5, Name = "Hamsters" }
          )
        );

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Image View: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLUh8.png)

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. Could you elaborate and perhaps point to which part of the code is not working as intended?

Comment: @Xerillio When I try to use create
So I have a category name I want to choose a category without the identity advancing but to choose a suitable category for the animal

Comment: @Xerillio What happens now when I select a category is not adapted to the new animal because the identity is advancing and it is a factor that there is no name for the category with the next identity

Comment: I think that your animal record should reference the CategoryId and not a new instance. It should be possible to create table entries for animals and categories in isolation. Also, if you wish to reassign a new category to an animal that already exists you just change the reference key in the animal entry.

Comment: @ChrisBD But I do not want to do it in isolation because I want to adapt each animal to its category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not quite clear to me what's going on, but I'll have a guess here...

In your `OnModelCreating` you probably want to add your data in the opposite order. Your `Animal` has a foreign key to `Category` which means, when adding data to `Animal`, the specified `Category` needs to already exist.

Try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Create all categories first
    _ = modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        entity.HasData(
            new { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Dogs" },
            new { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Cats" },
            new { CategoryId = 3, Name = "Birds" },
            new { CategoryId = 4, Name = "Rabbits" },
            new { CategoryId = 5, Name = "Hamsters" }
        )
    );

    // Then create an animal with the first category above
    modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasData(
            new
            {
                AnimalId = 1,
                Name = "Shoko",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now
                    .AddYears(-1)
                    .AddMonths(-1)
                    .AddDays(-12),
                Description = "Friendly and loyal",
                CategoryId = 1,
                PhotoUrl = "ShokoDog.jpg"
            });
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: it does not work for me @Xerillio

Comment: @YosefAbada Could you elaborate? What does "not work" mean? Did you make sure you database is empty first?

Comment: Yes it is empty because I did in the database delete program and re-create
And as for the detail: it gives me the same problem I talked about before the advanced identity

Comment: @YosefAbada What if you delete this line from your code? `Category = new Category();`

Comment: That I remove it so it does not allow me to add at all